# LFS - Version SVN-20200315 - GLibc fails to *install*

Tags: lfs

I'm just following the LFS book and when I reach the point to install GLibc the second time, in the chroot, it builds fine, but when I run `make install`, it errors. It installs a file to `/usr/share/i18n/charmaps`, but then proceeds to try and gzip it and it can't find it (at least that's what I think its doing).

The last 30ish lines of the log:

```
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /sources/glibc-2.31/build/gnu/lib-names-64.h /usr/include/gnu/lib-names-64.h
/usr/bin/install -c /sources/glibc-2.31/build/iconv/iconvconfig /usr/sbin/iconvconfig.new
mv -f /usr/sbin/iconvconfig.new /usr/sbin/iconvconfig
/usr/bin/install -c /sources/glibc-2.31/build/iconv/iconv_prog /usr/bin/iconv.new
mv -f /usr/bin/iconv.new /usr/bin/iconv
make[2]: Leaving directory '/sources/glibc-2.31/iconv'
make  subdir=locale -C locale ..=../ subdir_install
make[2]: Entering directory '/sources/glibc-2.31/locale'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 langinfo.h /usr/include/langinfo.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 locale.h /usr/include/locale.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 bits/locale.h /usr/include/bits/locale.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 bits/types/locale_t.h /usr/include/bits/types/locale_t.h
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 bits/types/__locale_t.h /usr/include/bits/types/__locale_t.h
/usr/bin/install -c /sources/glibc-2.31/build/locale/libBrokenLocale.so /lib/libBrokenLocale-2.31.so.new
mv -f /lib/libBrokenLocale-2.31.so.new /lib/libBrokenLocale-2.31.so
echo `../scripts/rellns-sh -p /lib/libBrokenLocale-2.31.so /lib/libBrokenLocale.so.1` /lib/libBrokenLocale.so.1 >> /sources/glibc-2.31/build/elf/symlink.list
rm -f /usr/lib/libBrokenLocale.so.new
/bin/sh ../scripts/rellns-sh /lib/libBrokenLocale.so.1 /usr/lib/libBrokenLocale.so.new
mv -f /usr/lib/libBrokenLocale.so.new /usr/lib/libBrokenLocale.so
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /sources/glibc-2.31/build/locale/libBrokenLocale.a /usr/lib/libBrokenLocale.a
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /sources/glibc-2.31/build/gnu/lib-names-64.h /usr/include/gnu/lib-names-64.h
/usr/bin/install -c /sources/glibc-2.31/build/locale/localedef /usr/bin/localedef.new
mv -f /usr/bin/localedef.new /usr/bin/localedef
/usr/bin/install -c /sources/glibc-2.31/build/locale/locale /usr/bin/locale.new
mv -f /usr/bin/locale.new /usr/bin/locale
make[2]: Leaving directory '/sources/glibc-2.31/locale'
make  subdir=localedata -C localedata ..=../ subdir_install
make[2]: Entering directory '/sources/glibc-2.31/localedata'
rm -f /usr/share/i18n/charmaps/ANSI_X3.110-1983 /usr/share/i18n/charmaps/ANSI_X3.110-1983.gz
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 charmaps/ANSI_X3.110-1983 /usr/share/i18n/charmaps/ANSI_X3.110-1983
gzip -9n /usr/share/i18n/charmaps/ANSI_X3.110-1983
make[2]: gzip: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [Makefile:310: /usr/share/i18n/charmaps/ANSI_X3.110-1983.gz] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/sources/glibc-2.31/localedata'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:470: localedata/subdir_install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/sources/glibc-2.31'
make: *** [Makefile:12: install] Error 2
```

Comment: I inlined your linked logfile since the life span on [termbin.com](https://termbin.com/) is only one month.

Comment: Oh, thanks, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. `gzip` wasn't installed so I installed it and it worked

It wasn't `gzip` that couldn't find the file, it was `gzip` that was not being found.